# WPF FlowDocument layout

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocument in which I need to insert many fragments of dynamic text at arbitrary positions.

For example, I need to place text "Hello" at `x = 10`, `y = 15` and text "World" at `x = 10`, `y = 20`.

I'm currently doing this using `Figure`. I create a `Run` with the text, put it in a `Paragraph`, and put all that in a `Figure`. From there I can set it's `VerticalOffset` and `HorizontalOffset`. Then I place all the figures in a `Paragraph` which I add to the `FlowDocument`.

Everything was going OK (it was the simplest approach I could came up) until I had to place two or three fragments of text **on the same line** (at the same `y` but different `x`).

For some reason it's putting each `Figure` on a new line instead of putting them all in the same line, let me illustrate:

**Expected:**

text1      text2                             text3

**Actual:**

text1
               text2
                                                   text3

Does anybody know how to remove that line break between figures? If you have a better approach to this problem I'm open to suggestions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ditched FlowDocument and went with XAML and used a Canvas... made my life much easier being able to place all text fields visually... much easier to maintain in the long run too.

Comment: We had to take that approach as well.